# Getting "ConnectionError: Error 10054 ..." just for touching a dataframe with parallel processing (Ray)

Tags: python, sockets, parallel-processing, host, ray

I'm getting an error every time my Ray parallel processing interacts with a specific data frame. What's really confusing is that if i make another data frame with the same shape and size and fill it with random strings, I do not get an error, and everything works fine. What's even MORE confusing, is that if I copy the data frame in any way (copy.deepcopy(), using loops to construct a new df that is a copy of the error-prone one, etc. you name it), I still get the error. I've even had the data frame converted to a different file type just in case it was a read issue somehow. I've even tested having my computer be at 128Gbs of RAM, and that didn't resolve anything either (talk about desperate). All research of this error code keeps leading me to network-related solutions, and yet this is a completely local program.

The bottom-of-the-line error:
"ConnectionError: Error 10054 while writing to socket. An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."
(I'll write the rest of the error at the end)

What is this file I'm using that Ray somehow hates once it's a dataframe python object? It's a .feather file, and it is about 10Gbs large with 22928487 rows × 21 columns, but before i use Ray on it, i make it smaller: 16593943 rows × 7 columns. Either way, i still get the error. In fact, even if i reduce the parallel work load on the file, it still gives me the error. Running this code takes a lot of RAM, because the data frame is so large. I have 64Gb of RAM and running makes my computer go up to about 45Gbs of RAM being used. Just to sit idly after reading the file (before using Ray), the computer is using a total of about 30Gbs of RAM. I haven't had a single issue with the feather data frame except that Ray (parallel) hates it. I also haven't gotten any RAM errors, except if I use this code on a different computer with 32Gbs or 16Gbs of RAM.

I have spent over 2 weeks now trying to figure this out, so I would really appreciate any help. I have reduced the code down as best I could to make it easier for anyone to chip in. I worry that reproduction may be difficult, because it's not like i can supply you with the massive file, because it is so large and also proprietary. Honestly, this could be a permissions error too instead, but i don't know.

Another note: the warning ray gives at the start happens no matter what in my experience- regardless of success or failures. Also, the dashboard is never accessible.

The error is listed completely below:

```
2021-02-19 16:59:00,436 INFO services.py:1173 -- View the Ray dashboard at http://127.0.0.1:8265
2021-02-19 17:01:14,967 WARNING worker.py:1034 -- Warning: The remote function __main__.ParallelFeather has size 6235199768 when pickled. It will be stored in Redis, which could cause memory issues. This may mean that its definition uses a large array or other object.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ConnectionResetError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py in send_packed_command(self, command, check_health)
    705             for item in command:
--> 706                 sendall(self._sock, item)
    707         except socket.timeout:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\redis\_compat.py in sendall(sock, *args, **kwargs)
      8 def sendall(sock, *args, **kwargs):
----> 9     return sock.sendall(*args, **kwargs)
     10 

ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-a691c5b84f12> in <module>
     33     StartFeather=int((i/processors)*len(DataFrame)/Modifier) #e.g. "1/12 of the column" divided by modifier to further illustrate how this doesn't work
     34     EndFeather=int(((i+1)/processors)*len(DataFrame)/Modifier) # e.g. "2/12 of the column" divided by modifier to further illustrate how this doesn't work
---> 35     (ParallelFeather.remote(Start=StartFeather,End=EndFeather)) # "+" does not work on ray objects with lists...sad
     36     i=i+1
     37 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ray\remote_function.py in _remote_proxy(*args, **kwargs)
     99         @wraps(function)
    100         def _remote_proxy(*args, **kwargs):
--> 101             return self._remote(args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    102 
    103         self.remote = _remote_proxy

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ray\remote_function.py in _remote(self, args, kwargs, num_returns, num_cpus, num_gpus, memory, object_store_memory, accelerator_type, resources, max_retries, placement_group, placement_group_bundle_index, placement_group_capture_child_tasks, override_environment_variables, name)
    205 
    206             self._last_export_session_and_job = worker.current_session_and_job
--> 207             worker.function_actor_manager.export(self)
    208 
    209         kwargs = {} if kwargs is None else kwargs

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ray\function_manager.py in export(self, remote_function)
    153                 "collision_identifier": self.compute_collision_identifier(
    154                     function),
--> 155                 "max_calls": remote_function._max_calls
    156             })
    157         self._worker.redis_client.rpush("Exports", key)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\redis\client.py in hset(self, name, key, value, mapping)
   3048                 items.extend(pair)
   3049 
-> 3050         return self.execute_command('HSET', name, *items)
   3051 
   3052     def hsetnx(self, name, key, value):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\redis\client.py in execute_command(self, *args, **options)
    898         conn = self.connection or pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
    899         try:
--> 900             conn.send_command(*args)
    901             return self.parse_response(conn, command_name, **options)
    902         except (ConnectionError, TimeoutError) as e:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py in send_command(self, *args, **kwargs)
    724         "Pack and send a command to the Redis server"
    725         self.send_packed_command(self.pack_command(*args),
--> 726                                  check_health=kwargs.get('check_health', True))
    727 
    728     def can_read(self, timeout=0):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py in send_packed_command(self, command, check_health)
    716                 errmsg = e.args[1]
    717             raise ConnectionError("Error %s while writing to socket. %s." %
--> 718                                   (errno, errmsg))
    719         except BaseException:
    720             self.disconnect()

ConnectionError: Error 10054 while writing to socket. An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

The code:

```
print("Replicating ConnectionError 10054 by using ray on a (large) dataframe.")
print("What's crazy is that If i construct a dataframe of equal shape filled with random strings 'foo','bar','baz', as values, i do not get the error")



ray.shutdown() #prevents an error.     %pip install -U ray
ray.init()   #necessary to use ray

DataFrame=Feather #22928487 rows × 21 columns
@ray.remote
def ParallelFeather(Start,End):
    ThisEncodedFeather=[]
    EncodedWholeInstitutionDictionary={}
    ListOfChosenDataTypes=["institution_unmatched","domain","domain_m","country","city","edt_id","zip"] #These are column titles of the 21 columns of the dataframe
    row=Start
    while row<End:
        #if type(Feather["institution_unmatched"][row]) is str:
         #   pass
        if type(DataFrame) is str:
            pass
        #    for ChosenDataType in ListOfChosenDataTypes:
         #       EncodedWholeInstitutionDictionary[ChosenDataType]=Feather[ChosenDataType][row]
          #  ThisEncodedFeather.append(EncodedWholeInstitutionDictionary)
        row+=1
    #return ThisEncodedFeather

EncodedFeathers=[]
processors=multiprocessing.cpu_count() #for me, this is 16
i=0
while i<processors: 
    StartFeather=int((i/processors)*len(DataFrame)) #e.g. "1/16 of the total length" 
    EndFeather=int(((i+1)/processors)*len(DataFrame)) # e.g. "2/16 of the total length"
    (ParallelFeather.remote(Start=StartFeather,End=EndFeather))
    i=i+1

print("If you have made it this far, then the error did not happen")
Errors=True
Errors=False
if not Errors:
    DecodedNestedFeathers=ray.get(EncodedFeathers) # gets me "ConnectionError: Error 10054 while writing to socket"
    DecodedFeathers=[]
    for FeatherNest in DecodedNestedFeathers:
        DecodedFeathers+=FeatherNest

ray.shutdown()

DecodedFeathers
```

Comment: The problem is likely that your remote function is too large (because of your data frame `DataFrame=Feather`). So, what's happening here is when you wrap your method with @ray.remote, the function is serialized. When it is serialized, all the object that is captured is included in the serialized data, which in your case is, `DataFrame=Feather`. The serialized data is going to Redis to be used in other processes, and it is likely that Redis is crasehd because this data is too big.

Comment: We are looking into a better solution to help resolving this type of issue. The best solution now is to always ray.put your dataframe and pass it as an argument.

Comment: Please look at the example I posted!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this instead? I explained the cause of your issue in the comment.

```py
DataFrameRef=ray.put(Feather) #22928487 rows × 21 columns
@ray.remote
def ParallelFeather(DataFrame, Start,End):
    ThisEncodedFeather=[]
    EncodedWholeInstitutionDictionary={}
    ListOfChosenDataTypes=["institution_unmatched","domain","domain_m","country","city","edt_id","zip"] #These are column titles of the 21 columns of the dataframe
    row=Start
    while row<End:
        #if type(Feather["institution_unmatched"][row]) is str:
         #   pass
        if type(DataFrame) is str:
            pass
        #    for ChosenDataType in ListOfChosenDataTypes:
         #       EncodedWholeInstitutionDictionary[ChosenDataType]=Feather[ChosenDataType][row]
          #  ThisEncodedFeather.append(EncodedWholeInstitutionDictionary)
        row+=1
    #return ThisEncodedFeather

EncodedFeathers=[]
processors=multiprocessing.cpu_count() #for me, this is 16
i=0
while i<processors: 
    StartFeather=int((i/processors)*len(DataFrame)) #e.g. "1/16 of the total length" 
    EndFeather=int(((i+1)/processors)*len(DataFrame)) # e.g. "2/16 of the total length"
    (ParallelFeather.remote(DataFrameRef, Start=StartFeather,End=EndFeather))
    i=i+1
```

Comment: It works now! Thanks! 

Extra notes:
I added a "return [6]" to the ParallelFeather() function's last line (outside of the row<End while loop), and I added "EncodedFeather.append()" to the ParallelFeather.remote() in the i<processors while loop. Once ray.get() triggers, my memory goes through the roof and crashes everything really hard. I changed processors to "2" to minimize the workload, and sure enough, i get [6,6] as my end result when the code finishes.
Now i just need to reduce RAM. Or...buy a lot more. (just for i<2, that's 56.6GBs of total RAM my computer is using)

Comment: You can also use a command `ray memory` to see the status of the distributed object store! (and this will show you which object uses the largest part of the memory).

Comment: I'd like to add that actually the solution provided above doesn't work for some reason on more complicated functions. My conclusion at this point is that ray can't work on large data frames.

Also "ray memory" just gives a name error. I've seen that online as well, and at least as it's instructed, it will give a name error.

Comment: Can you tell me a little bit more about what it means by "doesn't work"? Is it crashed with other errors?

Comment: Sure thing, and I apologize for the vagueness; i would love to be more specific. By "doesn't work," i mean I get the same ConnectionError as first talked about in this post. It is the same error that was apparantly solved by you by changing an argument's value into a ray object. Alas, when i changed the functions to be more complicated, Ray flipped out and gave me the connection error again.

Comment: I have worked on this (even) more, and I have discovered that in all honesty, the original file is just too dang big. What's fascinating is that even if i make another dataframe that takes only a portion of the original giant dataframe, python "knows" that the giant dataframe is being talked about. Therefore, reducing the size of the original dataframe will work, albeit this makes coding more laborous; reading the file as smaller (skiprows=range(...), nrows=...) is the only workaround i could find, but at least that worked despite having to run the code several times for each chunk.